# Can the data be posted with the form structure in the list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a build for the screen on which I received payment information on the eCommerce-like page I was working on. Here, the person can trade on his / her name or someone else and I need to add a button to update the incoming information.

In order to update the information I have a method in the controller, but when I press the button, I cannot send the data to the controller. I noticed that this is not because `Foreach` is printed. Does anyone have this problem or know the solution?

```
@model List<CartVM>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<form>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <div>
            <h4>
                @item.SubcategoryName
                <label asp-for="@item.Amount" class="col-md-4 pull-right text-right">Total Amount: @item.Amount TL</label>
                <label asp-for="@item.Count" class="col-md-3 pull-right">Count: @item.Count</label>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="order-buttons">
            <input asp-controller="Payment" asp-action="Edit" class="btn bg-primary" value="Edit All" />
        </div>
    </li>
}
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public void Edit(CartVM cartVM)
{
    _cartService.AddToCart(cartVM);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Edit` be marked as `[HttpPost]` or add `method="post"` to your form?

Comment: Thank you for your support. When I try adding HttpPost, I get the same result, I just managed to drop the meth, but this time the model came in null. In addition, I noticed that while the page is running, the item in the asp-for tag comes directly from the item.Amount's value is not directly "item.Amount".


`<label class="col-md-4 pull-right text-right" for="item_Amount">Amount : 1 TL</label>`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? First, your view are labels which are not able to change the values, what do you want to update to `Edit(CartVM cartVM)`? Second, all items are in single form, do you want to submit all data or specific `CartVM`. Thrid, for `Edit(CartVM cartVM)`, it seems to be edit purpose, but you are using `_cartService.AddToCart(cartVM);` which is add operation. Check [ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core - CRUD - 2 of 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-2.0) for get started.